# How Do I Specify tsconfig.json in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I've created a new TypeScript Project from existing code, then added a tsconfig.json from within VS 2017.

The above process cleaned up a couple hundred errors, but now there are two left that read:

`Build: The specified path does not exist 'C:\path\to\project\parent\tsconfig.json`

If I add a second tsconfig.json to the path it's complaining about, I get more errors.

Basically, it's expecting a tsconfig.json in my project folder and also in my solution folder. I want it to only care about the one in my project folder.